# How to wakeup sensor nodes in wsn using ns2?

Tags: sensors, ns2

i am new to ns2,i want to simulate routing protocol in wireless sensor networks,anyone tell me how to wake up sensor nodes by transferring sink node wakeup message and how to get node position?

Answer (score 0):

Hello read Leach protocol in ns-2

you will learn how the nodes are sleep and awake.